# como evitar el envio de campos vacios en html con php

Tags: javascript, html

```
<table>
                <tr>
                    <th>Nombre</th>
                    <td><input type="text" name="nombre"/></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <th>Apellido</th>
                    <td><input type="text" name="apellido"/></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <th>Cedula</th>
                    <td><input type="text" name="cedula"/></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <th>Sexo</th>
                    <td><input type="text" name="sexo"/></td>
                </tr>
</table>
<button type="submit" onclick ="guardarDatos();">Guardar</button>
```

Tengo el código que se supone que me debe funcionar así:

```
var DATOS = [];
function guardarDatos(){
    inps= document.getElementsByTagName('input');

    for(k in inps){
        if(inps[k].value==''){
            alert("Debe Completar "+inps[k].id);
            return false;
        }
    }   
}
```

Pero no hace nada.

Comment: ¿PHP? Eso parece más JavaScript.

Comment: @Shaz el codigo de validar los campos si estan vacios lo traje de java script pero estoy haciendo ahora otro en php .. no se puede utilizar? soy nuevo en este lenguaje

Comment: Tú código de JS está completo? En el ejemplo te falta cerrar la llave de la función, o eso es sólo un error de copy/paste? Lo probé en jsFiddle y si te valida que no dejes campos vacíos https://jsfiddle.net/lixusrarnavo/1sg5onf9/

Comment: solo fue un error de copy/paste si

Comment: ok me fije en lo que dijiste si tenias razon me faltaba una llave gracias

Comment: @SamuelIgnacioSusanaConfesor ,si hay error aqui la solucion https://jsfiddle.net/1sg5onf9/1/ estas preguntando en el alert por id y los inputs no tienen id, lo cambie a name

Comment: gracias a todos

Comment: @Lixus una duda cuando me arroja la alerta que falta algun campo por llenar aun asi me registra una linea

Comment: Tienes que poner más bien esa función en el submit de tu forma `'onsubmit=...'` para que cuando regreses `false` entonces ahí se detenga el envío de la forma

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hola  podrias agregar el siguiente codigo HTML5 al input :

```html
  Username: <input type="text" name="usrname" required>
```

y listo tu problema de validacion de campo sera solucionado nativamente por HTML5 sin javascript.

[Fuente](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_input_required.asp)

pero si tu proposito es validar con Javascript aqui tienes un ejemplo explicado linea por linea:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script>
//creamos un pequeña funcion la cual sera llamada desde el html
function validateForm() {
//capturamos el valor(value) de myfrom/fname 
    var x = document.forms["myForm"]["fname"].value;
  //validamos para ver si existe un valor agregado al input
    if (x == "") {

// y si no fue agregado ninguna informacion que te mande un alert notificando que es obligatorio.
        alert("Name must be filled out");
        return false;
    }
}
</script>
</head>
<body>



<form name="myForm" action="/action_page_post.php"
onsubmit="return validateForm()" method="post">
Name: <input type="text" name="fname">
<input type="submit" value="Submit">
</form>

</body>
</html>
```

y un consejo mio, si estas usando un formulario para guardar datos o algo parecido evita la tabla, porque  por eso? [Porque no debes usar tablas para formularios ni Div, solo para ordenar informacion traida de la BD.](http://collaboradev.com/2014/07/07/never-use-html-tables-ever/)